# Why my code does not return what should it?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm new in python, I tried some exercises about `numpy`, but in this doce result, I find the last 2 numbers isn't correct. I think they should be `9**9` and `10**10`, in my limited experience with python, I can´t understand how it come to this result.

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(1,11)
xs,ys=np.meshgrid(a,a)
xs**ys
```

`-808182895, 1410065408]],
      dtype=int32)`

these two results I don´t understand how they come? They shouldn't be `9**9` as `3486784401` and `10**10` as `10000000000`.

Comment: Your code gives the right result for me (3486784401 and 10000000000). Could you explain what you are after?

Comment: [         1,       1024,      59049,    1048576,    9765625,
          60466176,  282475249, 1073741824, -808182895, 1410065408]],
      dtype=int32)

Comment: this is the last line of the putput of ``xs**ys``, I don´t understand how come `-808182895, 1410065408`.

Comment: I think , It should be `9**9`=`3486784401` and `10**10` =`10000000000`.???

Comment: Right, I got it. It's because your array is a `int32` array. The maximum value of a 32-bits integer is  `2,147,483,647`. If I cast my np.array to an int32 I get the same result you get.

I am not sure how to solve this, and whether 64-bit integers are somehow supported for 32-bit systems. There is nothing wrong with the code, however.

Comment: Ok ,so I understand now, Thx.

Comment: finally, I fixed it with this `import numpy as np
a=np.arange(1,11)
xs,ys=np.meshgrid(a,a)
xs.astype(np.int64)**ys.astype(np.int64)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output correct answer, set the dtype as np.int64.
By default numpy guess the datatype implicitly (numpy guessed dtype as np.int32).

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(1,11,dtype=np.int64)
xs,ys=np.meshgrid(a,a)
xs**ys
```